# What does "sell it" mean?

Tags: meaning

In drama movie *Bombshell (2019)*, Rudi is talking to DC bureau chief, who is asking her sexual favours:

> Rudi: We're friends. Professionals. We have a great professional vibe.
>
> Rudi (inner voice): Now **sell it**.
>
> Rudi: I just don't do that. I've never had to do that for a job.

What does "sell it" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[One of the meanings of **sell** is "to persuade someone of something".](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sell)

Rudi is basically saying to herself, "Be convincing about this."